# Ломается вёрстка при ссылках на vk

Tags: html, css, modx

Вопрос немного странный, я впервые с подобным сталкиваюсь, но, может, Вы знаете в чем у меня проблема.
Есть очень простой сайт, построенный на modx revo.

В двух словах: элементы сайта выводятся там "чанками", код в этих чанках "не правился со стороны клиента". Всё, что делал клиент - просто добавлял новости, а они, соответственно, по заранее созданной логике выводились на сайте.

Проблема наблюдалась только на главной странице, где выводятся записи из разделов "Мероприятия" и "Новости".

Как это выглядит:
[image: true]

Как это выглядело "вчера":
[image: false]

Важно:

1. При добавлении записей указывается лишь картинки в доп поле
2. Структура вёрстке (классы, col-* и пр.) никак не задаются при добавлении записей.

Как решилась вчера проблема:

1. Отключал по очереди последние новости и "всё заработало".
2. Пересохранил новости заново.
3. Проблема решена.

Но, откуда могла взяться проблема-то? У "проблемных" новостей в описании была стандартная гиперссылка на запись в ВКонтакте, и эта же гиперссылка в инспектора кода поднималась на один уровень с "шаблоном отдельной записи" и тем самым ломала вёрстку.

Извините, но совсем не понимаю, как подобное может быть?

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 border__right">
        <div class="content__custom">
          <div class="content__news">
            <h3>Новости <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></h3>
            <div class="row">
              // Начало шаблона отдельной записи
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="фс.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Фестиваль " Её величество Мама " в г.Советск">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 27.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/festival-eyo-velichestvo-mama-v-g.sovetsk.html">Фестиваль "Её величество Мама" в г.Советск</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p>Сегодня прошел <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="https://vk.com/cspsova?w=wall-174640861_125116"&#8230;</a></span></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              // конец шаблона отдельной записи
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/hyZi5WE4kmA.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Экскурсия в пожарную часть">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 27.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/ekskursiya-v-pozharnuyu-chast.html">Экскурсия в пожарную часть</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p> </p>
<p>Подопечные семьи ЦСП "С.О.В.А." г.Узловая от всего сердца говорят спасибо руководству <a&#8230;</a></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/сл.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Раздача молока Слобода">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 27.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/razdacha-moloka-sloboda.html">Раздача молока Слобода</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p><span>Сегодня почти для 500 семей состоялась <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="https://vk.com/cspsova?w=wall-174640861_124761"&#8230;</a></span></span></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="пс.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Раздача прыг- скокеров и прилипал">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 25.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-4.html">Раздача прыг- скокеров и прилипал</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p>Кто в дом принес пакет прыг-скокеров, прилипал и наклейки? Конечно же наши подопечные. Для них это&#8230;</p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/OmW0KlFZvVY.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Раздача каш и сокосодержащих напитков">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 24.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet.html">Раздача каш и сокосодержащих напитков</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p>Семьи Тульской области от всей души говорят спасибо Благотворительному фонду продовольствия "Русь" за&#8230;</p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="шс.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="МЕГА-ШОУ СЕЛЕЗНЁВЫХ">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 24.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="novosti/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-5.html">МЕГА-ШОУ СЕЛЕЗНЁВЫХ</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p><span>Благодарим организаторов МЕГА-ШОУ СЕЛЕЗНЁВЫХ за невероятные впечатления, которые Вы нам подарили!&#8230;</span></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content__hr"></div>
          <div class="content__news">
            <h3>Мероприятия <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></h3>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/скользко.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ФЕСТИВАЛЬ " СКОЛЬЗКО! БЫСТРО! ВЕСЕЛО! "">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 27.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="meropriyatiya/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-8.html">ФЕСТИВАЛЬ "СКОЛЬЗКО! БЫСТРО! ВЕСЕЛО!"</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p><span>Спорт - жизнь! </span>Зима - это красиво и очень весело! Не грустите дома около телевизора,&#8230;</p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="футбол.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ФУТБОЛЬНЫЙ МАРАФОН">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 27.11.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="meropriyatiya/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-7.html">ФУТБОЛЬНЫЙ МАРАФОН</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p><span>26 апреля 2019г. состоялся открытый 10-ти часовой <strong>футбольный марафон. </strong></span><br&#8230;</p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/IuyibRgMOmY.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ФЕСТИВАЛЬ " МУДРАЯ СОВА "">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 01.09.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="meropriyatiya/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-6.html">ФЕСТИВАЛЬ "МУДРАЯ СОВА"</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p>1 сентября 2019г. в Центральном парке культуры и отдыха им. П.П. Белоусова с размахом прошел<strong>&#8230;</strong></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="content__news-item">
                  <div class="content__news-photo">
                    <img src="images/радуга.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ФЕСТИВАЛЬ " РАДУГА ДЕТСТВА "">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-date">
                    <span>Дата: 08.06.2019</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content__news-header">
                    <h5><a href="meropriyatiya/lorem-ipsum-dolor-site-amet-9.html">ФЕСТИВАЛЬ "РАДУГА ДЕТСТВА"</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <!--         <div class="content__news-description">
    <p><span>8 июня 2019г. на Казанской Набережной Тульского кремля прошёл <strong>фестиваль "Радуга детства"</strong>,&#8230;</span></p>
</div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content__hr"></div>
          <div class="content__advantages">
            <h3>Что мы делаем?</h3>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="content__advantages-icon">
                  <img src="images/icon-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content__advantages-info">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ullam veniam adipisci eaque quibusdam impedit sed nam a, tempora sunt porro. Perspiciatis itaque, repellat unde dignissimos sapiente rem ipsum perferendis.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="content__advantages-icon">
                  <img src="images/icon-3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content__advantages-info">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ullam veniam adipisci eaque quibusdam impedit sed nam a, tempora sunt porro. Perspiciatis itaque, repellat unde dignissimos sapiente rem ipsum perferendis.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="content__advantages-icon">
                  <img src="images/icon-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content__advantages-info">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ullam veniam adipisci eaque quibusdam impedit sed nam a, tempora sunt porro. Perspiciatis itaque, repellat unde dignissimos sapiente rem ipsum perferendis.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="content__photo">
          <h3>Фото <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></h3>
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="content__photo-item">
              <div class="content__photo-photo">
                <img src="/assets/gallery/1/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="content__photo-header">
                <h5>123123123</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__photo-item">
              <div class="content__photo-photo">
                <img src="/assets/gallery/1/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="content__photo-header">
                <h5></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__photo-item">
              <div class="content__photo-photo">
                <img src="/assets/gallery/1/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="content__photo-header">
                <h5></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__photo-item">
              <div class="content__photo-photo">
                <img src="/assets/gallery/1/4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="content__photo-header">
                <h5></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__photo-item">
              <div class="content__photo-photo">
                <img src="/assets/gallery/1/5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="content__photo-header">
                <h5></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content__hr"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Нужен код (не всей страницы и стилей), либо ссылка на страницу.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 добавил часть кода, ответственного за вывод проблемных материалов. Ссылка: https://cspsova.ru

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 слушайте, я тут подумал. У меня до этого выводись первые 300 символов из содержимого публикации. А если в эти 300 символов попадала ссылка, частично обрезанная, т.е. <a href="....." и на этом обрезалась.
Могло ли это сломать вёрстку?